# Is there any IDE like Intellij for Unix shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

On daily basis, I do write a lot of shell scripts for a different project.

I wanted to know, is there a way where I can write a lot of scripts project wise as we do create in IntelliJ/eclipse. As well as I could able to run those scripts from IDE only. I think this will create more clarity and my development speed will also increase.

Currently what i do, using FileZilla to connect to the server I open particular script as I set Sublime text as default file editor it opens into that only. I do make changes into the file and once I save it changes easily reflected into server using which to some extent solve my problem.

But does anyone knows!! is there any way/tool/software which could do all these steps/tasks as a whole.
That help to boost our productivity as IntelliJ and other IDEs are doing for many decades.

Answer (score 1):

A better process is to have your scripts stored in git repository.

Clone the repository locally, edit your scripts using an editor/IDE of your choice. Test and once your changes are ready commit and push to the repository. Then update the repository copy on the server.

Comment: but what about testing and run the script from that IDE how i can run it into server from local either any IDE/editor

Comment: @IndrajeetGour You should have a local development environment where you can run your tests.